# gRaphaël 3d pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, graphael

Is there any simple way of creating a 3D pie chart using gRaphaël? I was looking to create something similar to http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/docs/charts/contents/ChartSS/Images/Pie_3D.jpg

Answer (score 1):

As of now there is no support for 3D Piechart using graphael. You'll have to code one on your own or use one of the libraries out there.